# How can I retrieve the user's WhatsApp number that's chatting with my IBM Watson Assistant Chatbot from Twilio that's integrated with WhatsApp

Tags: twilio, chatbot, whatsapp, watson-assistant

I have integrated my IBM Watson assistant chatbot with WhatsApp that uses Twilio, and at the moment in Twilio I have a Trial WhatsApp Sandbox Number to be able to test the chatbot within WhatsApp.

Everything works fine till now but I am stuck a bit: I want from within the chat between my chatbot and my user, to automatically retrieve the user's phone number and send it back to IBM chatbot. Is this feasible? Even if I have a trial phone number at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Twilio will send a couple of parameters to your webhook when you receive a message. If you want to read the phone number, you can read one of these parameters:

- [`From`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#request-parameters)

  The phone number or Channel address that sent this message.
- [`WaId`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters)

  The sender's WhatsApp ID (typically a phone number)

Comment: I tried these and nothing worked(the Webhook URL of my Chatbot is In "When a message comes in" section & it works)
In my Chatbot’s Backend I did this:
const accountSid = 'ACCOUNTSID';
const authToken = 'AUTHTOKEN';
//const twilio = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const twilio = require('twilio');
Then in my function:
const num= params.WaId;
& tried :
//const num= params.From ; //twilio.WaId; // twilio.From; //twilio.from; // params.from;
The value returned is undefined & the “params” 's taking the ones passed in IBM Watson Assistant manually and not the one from Twilio.

Comment: If the IBM Watson Assistant redacts the param, then this seems to be an IBM issue.

Comment: Then what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

IBM chat bot already doest it for you and it can be accessed via `${system_integrations.channel.private.user.id}`

see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-expression-integration-variables

Comment: Hello, I hope you're doing well, thank you for your help, but can you provide me with more details about how to do it? Because when I do it it gives the error message that the system_integrations isn't defined. ( I know that message means that I should define it but in the link that you left it, says that's already contained in the above JSON object )
Thank you for bearing with me

Comment: If u r using the built in integration, it should be defined. How r u using it? Pls provide screenshots with errors

Comment: console.log( "HELLOO TWILIOO: ", `${system_integrations.channel.private.user.id}`)

Comment: U should author this in the watson assistant action editor https://medium.com/ibm-watson/designing-and-building-actions-in-the-new-watson-assistant-31898d386917